# Instantiation of local variable through another function

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm using Delphi 10.2.3 Tokyo and VCL.

I create a function that calls another function to instantiate a local variable in the first function, like this:

```
Procedure TForm1.SetQuery(var aQuery : TFDQuery);
begin
  if not(Assigned(aQuery)) then
    aQuery := TFDQuery.Create(self);  // Never executed ???
  aQuery.Connection := self.FDConnection1;  // Access Violation -> aQuery isn't instanciate !
end;

Procedure TForm1.DoSomething;
var
  vQry : TFDQuery;
begin
  SetQuery(vQry);

end;
```

The line `aQuery := TFDQuery.Create(self);` is never executed. So it causes an Access Violation afterwards.

What am I missing?

Comment: Local variables for the most part aren't initialized, and therefore the test for `Assigned(vQry);` is true (there is random garbage assigned to the variable, so it's not `nil`). Set `vQry := nil;`, or better yet stop creating objects where the responsibility for cleanup is not clear. If you insist on creating one elsewhere, at least make it a function, where you would use `vQry := CreateQuery;`, which could be followed by a `try..finally` block to clean up afterwards.

Comment: Yes i understand it. and you are fully right. the vQry.Free is in the same block inside the "DoSomething" procedure. (so Freeing the object is well managed). It's just a function that encapsulate some basic code like create the FDquery, connect to DB, exécute the query and link it to the datasource (you only see piece of the code here). I use this function to make it more standard in our application and to make developpement faster. (one line of code instead of 15 and more readable also).